# Warning messages for mixed lmer model in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I am attempting to run a linear mixed model in R. However I get the impression something is going very wrong.

All the variables in the model are continuous apart from group which is a factor with two levels. My dependant variable has been log transformed to resolve normality issues. In addition, all of my independent variables in the model have undergone scaling to give standard deviations of 1 and means of 0. I didn't do this to the dependant variable as scaling the log transformed produced NANs.

Example code of treatment to independent variables:

```
data$age2 = scale(data$age)
```

The only other thing to say about the variables is that each subject has two values for time2. This variable is a measure of average reaction speed on two different types of questions in a test. The data was in wide format where each participant occupies one row. I now have the data in long format where each participant has two rows. The rows in long format are identical apart from two differences. There is a column specifying the different levels of time2 (easy/hard). And another column specifying the two different scores for time2.

My model looks something like this:

```
(T_log ~ 1 + age2 + IQ2 + group + GermanScore2 + time2 + group:GermanScore2:time2 
                  + (1 + GermanScore2|subjects), data = data)
```

As well as the fixed effects, the model examines random intercepts for subjects taking part. There is also a three ways interaction term in the fixed effects.

However I get various warnings/errors running the model. I am wondering and guessing if this is something to do with how I have treated the variables. Either that or the model is too complex (the plan is to work backwards once running the most complex model).

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.246526 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?
```

In actual fact, the model above has a slightly simplified random effect structure than the one I want to consider. I really want to look at:

```
(T_log ~ 1 + age2 + IQ2 + group + GermanScore2 + time2 + group:GermanScore2:time2 
                  + (1 + GermanScore2|subjects), data = data)
```

This model adds in random slopes for each subject on a German test score.

However that model produces an error:

```
Error: number of observations (=152) <= number of random effects (=152) for term (1 + bilec_total_input | part_no); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable
```

Anyone have any idea what has gone wrong? If you are generous enough to answer, keep in mind I am a stats / R dummy. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are over-fitting and don't have enough data for the model you are trying to run. Try a simpler model, these might be helpful https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37647/what-is-the-minimum-recommended-number-of-groups-for-a-random-effects-factor & https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13166/rs-lmer-cheat-sheet

Comment: Thanks. I wish that was the case. Even dropping variables to form a simple model throws out the same problems. Although I do agree that when working properly the model is likely overfitted.

Comment: Could it be that the model is unidentified because you have only 2 measurements per person and try to estimate both a random intercept and a random slope (i.e. 2 parameters) per person? If this is the problem, removing fixed predictors does not help but it should work as soon as you take out the random slope.